# Multilabel classification of a sequence, how to do it?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, classification, multilabel-classification, transformer-model

I am quite new to the deep learning field especially Keras. Here I have a simple problem of classification and I don't know how to solve it. What I don't understand is how the general process of the classification, like converting the input data into tensors, the labels, etc.

Let's say we have three classes, `1, 2, 3`.

There is a sequence of classes that need to be classified as one of those classes. The dataset is for example

- Sequence `1, 1, 1, 2` is labeled `2`
- Sequence `2, 1, 3, 3` is labeled `1`
- Sequence `3, 1, 2, 1` is labeled `3`

and so on.

This means the input dataset will be

```py
[[1, 1, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 3, 3],
 [3, 1, 2, 1]]
```

and the label will be

```py
[[2],
 [1],
 [3]]
```

Now one thing that I do understand is to one-hot encode the class. Because we have three classes, every `1` will be converted into `[1, 0, 0]`, `2` will be `[0, 1, 0]` and `3` will be `[0, 0, 1]`. Converting the example above will give a dataset of 3 x 4 x 3, and a label of 3 x 1 x 3.

Another thing that I understand is that the last layer should be a softmax layer. This way if a test data like (e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4]`) comes out, it will be softmaxed and the probabilities of this sequence belonging to class 1 or 2 or 3 will be calculated.

Am I right? If so, can you give me an explanation/example of the process of classifying these sequences?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question looks strange, seems like you almost know who to feed in the input and the representation of the output. At the same time, you don't want to know the working of any architectures.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa I'm sorry, let me edit the question. Maybe you are right, I almost know how to feed in the input but I think I need a code example as well. I actually did try a few examples in Keras but so far I got various errors like the tensor size does not match, etc. Because I actually know how LSTM for example works, in theory, and I saw working examples of an LSTM or image classification for example with CNN, but not this kind of problem.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa well and what I meant was I don't need in-depth explanation of how a model works, but if there are people who want to kindly explain to help clearing things up, I am surely grateful

Comment: Could you also post the code that you have tried and the error that you have got? So that you would get the right solution.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa well because the code that I wrote used a very specific library that is why I don't place the example here, and I also want to know the general idea instead of how my specific code works too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few clarifications that you seem to be asking about.

- This point was confusing so I deleted it.
- If your input data has the shape (4), then your input tensor will have the shape (batch_size, 4).
- Softmax is the correct activation for your prediction (last) layer
  given your desired output, because you have a classification problem
  with multiple classes. This will yield output of shape (batch_size,
  3). These will be the probabilities of each potential classification, summing to one across all classes. For example, if the classification is class `0`, then a single prediction might look something like `[0.9714,0.01127,0.01733]`.
- Batch size isn't hard-coded to the network, hence it is represented in model.summary() as `None`. E.g. the network's last-layer output shape can be written `(None, 3)`.
- Unless you have an applicable alternative, a softmax prediction layer requires a `categorical_crossentropy` loss function.
- The architecture of a network remains up to you, but you'll at least need a way in and a way out. In Keras (as you've tagged), there are a few ways to do this. Here are some examples:

Example with Keras Sequential

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(4,))) # sequence of length four
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax')) # three possible classes
```

Example with Keras Functional

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(4,))
x = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(input_tensor)
model = Model(input_tensor, x)
```

Example including input tensor shape in first functional layer (either Sequential or Functional):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(666, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,)))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The softmax output that you wrote as an example, this is the output if I do not use one-hot encoding? Or it does not matter whether one-hot encoding was used or not? And that means the output of softmax is always set to the number of labels (i.e. the size of vocabulary)?

Comment: Correct! The output of softmax is indeed to be set to the number of labels. In fact, it's best practice to explicitly link the number of units to the number of labels. E.g. `Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax')` If you need to use one-hot encoding on some `y` columns, that's fine, just know that it will change the *number* of columns in `y`, and thereby the shape of the network's output. As you can see, then, having your output layer reference the variable shape of the number of columns makes the shape of predictions automatically adjust! Cruise-control. :)

Comment: Just to be clear, then, if you had `y` with column `colors` with values `['red', 'green', 'blue']`, one-hot encoding would produce a new dataframe with columns `[is_red, is_green, is_blue]` and values `[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]`. The number of units in your output layer would be 3 (the length of the array of columns; the number of labels). Predictions from this network, then, would have the shape (batch_size, 3), and an output like in the third bullet point above.

Comment: Thank you so much! Good answer. I will leave this not marked as answer for a few days in case anyone wants to provide other explanations as well.

Comment: Hi again! Just wanted to point out [this bundle](https://www.humblebundle.com/books/artificial-intelligence-deep-learning-books), I picked it up the other day and dove into the Keras specific one, and the first chapter reminded me of you because it covers a lot of this in much better words than mine.